# Is there a way to regain the daily power on a miss?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, powers

Missing on a daily power is a big let down and happens, frankly, a lot around our gaming table. Is there a way to introduce a rule that allows regaining the daily on a miss?

Comment: Are you asking "is there a way to introduce a rule…?" or are you asking for people's house rules? Or are you asking for a system-friendly methodology for designing such a house rule?

Comment: As veritascitor's comment mentions below, nearly all daily powers are reliable or do something on a miss (typically half damage).  Is this not sufficient?

Comment: I think there's some feats for classes that allow recovery of Encounter or Daily powers, but I can't name them off the top of my head.  Otherwise, I agree that Miss effects and Reliable powers should generally be sufficient compensation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many fighter daily powers come with the **reliable** keyword, which prevents the expenditure of the power on a miss. You could enhance other powers with the reliable keyword, but if doing so you would need to be careful not to tread too far on the fighters' toes (especially if there is one in the group)

Comment: Note that almost all daily powers have either the reliable keyword, or effects that happen regardless of a hit or miss.

Answer (score 3):

One house rule I've heard, but not tried, is that players can spend an action point after missing with their daily to not use it up.  This is instead of getting an additional action per normal use of action points.

Comment: A house rule I've played with along the same vein allows players to spend an action point to re-roll any die.

Answer (score 3):

The only real rule is the reliable keyword that Simon Withers mentions up above.

Another house-rule I have seen (but don't use) is that you can allow a PC to spend a healing surge to recover a daily power on a miss (and forgo the effects on a miss), or spend two healing surges, and keep the miss effect.

This is a simulation-y type measure because the PC is literally losing hit points in order to use his power- he's exhausting himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can find something similar in the breakage rules in Darksun which run something along the lines of 'Take damage to your weapon in return for a reroll after a natural 1. While it wont fix the 2-9 wiffles, it can help head towards that direction.

Rerolls are much like regaining a daily power.